# Do [anti-patterns] encourage opinion-based questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, opinion-based

I've stumbled upon this very old question: [Is global constants an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263954)

It seems very clear to me that this is opinion-based. It's not focused on a particular problem, and answers may be disputable (accepted answer just very bad). It could probably belong to Code Review. I didn't vote to close it because it's very old and has upvotes, but maybe it should be closed.

However my question is about the tag - isn't it suggesting that such questions and all like "Is doing X bad?" are on-topic here?

Only 429 questions are tagged with it, along with more popular [design-patterns]. After quick look I would say that third of them are opinion-based.

Related question I've found (not about the tag): [Is a question about design patterns too opinionated for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256663)

From my comment: when new user writes a question and sees that tag, they may think that question like "Is singleton anti-pattern?" are on-topic. I think, that this tag encourages bad questions. And considering small ammount of questions tagged with it, it may be a candidate for burnination.

Additionally, questions with this tag, that aren't opinion based are about specific technology/language/problem. I don't see any purpose of this tag being used.

Comment: I wouldn't say that [[tag:anti-patterns]] is specifically off topic no, as the reason they are doesn't need to be opinionated. Take something like the [UPSERT Anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) in T-SQL; it's been well discussed over the years why checking if the row exists first is counterproductive and those reasons aren't opinionated, they're factual.

Comment: @Larnu I agree, that they doesn't need to be opinionated, but often they do

Comment: If you found a 2:1 majority were *not* opinion based then what really is the point you are trying to make here?

Comment: Because *some* questions are opinionated doesn't make *all* of them off-topic, @DimaRostopira . If you find a question that is off-topic because it's opinionated VTC is, or comment to the user to explain how they could change their question to make it less opinionated.

Comment: @charlietfl when new user writes a question and sees that tag, they may think that question like "Is singleton anti-pattern?" are on-topic. I think, that this tag encourages bad questions. And considering small ammount of questions tagged with it, it may be a candidate for burnination.

Comment: Ok then make those arguments in the question. The answer to the question in your title is not "yes" if it's not true for the majority

Comment: People will ask the opinion-based question whether there's a tag for it or not.

Comment: If the tag has only 429 questions and only few of them are opinion based, how does it encourage bad questions? It does barely seem to encourage *any* questions.

Comment: @DimaRostopira by that logic the tags [[tag:sql-server]], [[tag:oracle]] and [[tag:mysql]] are off topic as they could ask "What is better, SQL Server, Oracle, or MySQL?" There few (no) tags that can attract no opinionated questions. There are tags that are inherently opinionated, but these are also few; [[tag:anti-patterns]] isn't one of them in my opinion.

Comment: @Larnu the difference is those tags have a purpose, this tag doesn't. I'm suggesting that this tag **may be** harmful **and** useless at the same time.

Comment: How is *harmful* @DimaRostopira ? You need to elaborate there.

Comment: @Larnu I've already explained that in the question, it will pop in tags field when user asks question (and comment)

Comment: Where @DimaRostopira ? You don't use the word "harmful" at all in the question... You say it might encourage bad questions, but you don't give any details on why you think that. Saying it might have a small amount of opinionated questions doesn't mean anything. I see plenty of opinionated questions all the time that are tagged with a single technology. Again, that doesn't make all of those off topic.

Comment: @Larnu I still do not agree with you. But even considering all of that, there is no reason for this tag to exist - there are just bunch of very unrelated questions. Also each language/framework has it's own patterns and anti-patterns. Your example will be just fine with [sql] tag

Comment: [Point and case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QJT5.png) (this was posted in the last few minutes). Clearly on topic tags; clearly opinionated question. The tags rarely have anything to do with if a question is opinionated.

Comment: @Larnu FYI the phrase is "case in point" (e.g. "here I make my entire case with one example point")

Comment: "I think, that this tag encourages bad questions" - probably. So does the Java tag though. So, so many bad questions.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree. Patterns and anti-patterns both unambiguously identify programming topics, so neither term really meets burnination criteria.

Also, being opinion-based to *some* degree is not intrinsically problematic - it's only a problem if it's so opinion-based that it's no longer possible to defend answers with facts and references. There is at least *some* room for professional judgment in the vast majority of questions, even on sites like Stack Overflow and Math.SE. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for some more details on this.